# What's the maximum number of repetitions allowed in a Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

In Python 2.7 and 3, the following works:

```
>>> re.search(r"a{1,9999}", 'aaa')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1f5d100>
```

but this gives an error:

```
>>> re.search(r"a{1,99999}", 'aaa')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
   return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 240, in _compile
   p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 523, in compile
   groupindex, indexgroup
RuntimeError: invalid SRE code
```

It seems like there is an upper limit on the number of repetitions allowed. Is this part of the regular expression specification, or a Python-specific limitation? If Python-specific, is the actual number documented somewhere, and does it vary between implementations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick manual binary search revealed the answer, specifically 65535:

```
>>> re.search(r"a{1,65535}", 'aaa')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2a9a68>
>>> 
>>> re.search(r"a{1,65536}", 'aaa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 240, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 523, in compile
    groupindex, indexgroup
OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded
```

This is discussed [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue13169):

> The limit is an implementation detail. The pattern is compiled into codes which are then interpreted, and it just happens that the codes are (usually) 16 bits, giving a range of 0..65535, but it uses 65535 to represent no limit and doesn't warn if you actually write 65535.

and

> The quantifiers use 65535 to represent no upper limit, so ".{0,65535}" is equivalent to ".*".

---

Thanks to the authors of the comments below for pointing a few more things out:

- CPython implements this limitation in [`_sre.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7268838063e1/Modules/_sre.c#l2694). (@LukasGraf)
- There is a constant `MAXREPEAT` in [`sre_constants.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sre_constants.py) that holds this max repetition value:

  ```
  >>> import sre_constants
  >>> 
  >>> sre_constants.MAXREPEAT
  65535
  ```

  (@MarkkuK. and @hcwhsa)

Comment: If you want to point this out in your answer: For CPython, this limitation is implemented in [`_sre.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7268838063e1/Modules/_sre.c#l2694)

Comment: Also, if you look in sre_constants.py, you will find `MAXREPEAT = 65535`

Comment: The limit can be found using: `import sre_constants;print sre_constants.MAXREPEAT`

Comment: Thanks, I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Note that `sre_constants.MAXREPEAT` isn't necessarily the limit in non-CPython implementations. Testing `len(re.search(r"a{1,999999}", "a"*(2*10**6)).group()) == 999999` succeeded on `PyPy 2.0.0-beta1`, `Jython 2.5.1+`, and `IronPython 2.9.9a0`.  This worked despite the fact `pypy` and `jython` both had `sre_constants.MAXREPEAT==65535`.

Comment: @DSM Yep, I believe even in CPython `MAXREPEAT` simply an informative constant (for developers to query), but the limit is actually enforced in [`_sre.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7268838063e1/Modules/_sre.c#l2694), and is probably also platform dependent.